# UI problem in LandscapeLeft mode in iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I've create an iPad application in LandscapeLeft mode and i've set my UI according to LandscapeLeft mode. But when i run my application it is showing UI in portrait mode. I can't figure out the problem.

Please reply.....

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Hello Aarti!!! i am also new to iphone. may i have your Skype Id or email so that we can ask Que directly and get the answers quickly. :P

Comment: you can add me on skype with name :-  mAc.0701

Answer (score 1):

Any application always launch in portrait mode.To launch in only landscape mode go to info.plist file and change supported orientation array accordingly

Or

In you view controller's shouldAutorotate method add following code

```
 if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    return YES;
 }

 return NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the below code in your application delegate file.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
}
```

Comment: hiii, thnx for ur reply.... but when i remove the NavigationController outlet from mainWindow.xib file.... application showing the perfect UI but when again i set the outlet it is appearing PortraitMode UI...

Comment: Then you have to copy - paste above code in your all UIViewController. Or you can edit your info.plist file. "Supported interface orientations" in this field there are four orientation remove two portrait orientation.